# Any way to print text to the CMD window without compiling it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console

Is there any way to print text to the CMD window without compiling the console window?

I'm asking this because I want to make a `--help` flag to a program I'm working on, but the release version of the program doesn't use the console at all and isn't built to use it, only the debug version is.

Does anyone have any suggestions, or even know if it's possible to do? If anyone wants to look at the code, or try it out for themselves, then the code is at [here](https://github.com/r-ex/LegionPlus), all the flags are in the `Main.cpp` file.

also with console do i mean SubSystem console if someone isn't aware

Comment: why would someone check the `--help` command of a non-console application? that makes no sense. Make a GUI help screen (or however the program actually runs)

Comment: I have written several programs that can be run from the cmd.exe and with the right command line arguments will operate as a command line program or if noting is provided show the GUI. However I do agree for a GUI only program I would not expect someone to know to start it with a --help command line argument.

Comment: it does for this program, why? because it can use a lot of flags without being console based, i use it mainly via console / batch, but the program works with or without the GUI

Comment: Windows programs are built to be either GUI or command based. It's possible to make one that works both ways but it's not simple.

Comment: I removed the comment because I was not sure that you were looking to allocate a console or exactly what was the problem.

Comment: my overall problem is that i can't print something out to the CMD (using the --help flag) when i don't have the console compiled (in visual studio settings)

Comment: Sounds like you need to wrap your `--help` processing inside of a `#ifdef _DEBUG` block. Then you can compile your debug build as a console app with CMD output, and compile your release build as a non-console app with GUI/no output. The alternative is to compile all of your builds as non-console, and then have your `--help` handler call [`AllocConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole) if there is no console already attached to the current process.

Comment: Explain _compile console_ please. That doesn't make sense. If you start a program from the console, you can always see what will be printed to the standard IO channels. And note that external links to code are considered like no code shown at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you need to pick the SubSystem when creating an app, the SubSystem is in my case Windows for the release and Console for debug, and you "can" only print on CMD if it's compiled as Console SubSystem

Comment: @Biast12 please put any additional information into your question. [Edit]!!

Comment: just to let you know, i can't wrap it inside a `#ifdef _DEBUG`, because then i can't make `ShowGUI = false`

Comment: *"I want to [use the console in] a program I'm working on, but the release version of the program doesn't use the console at all"* -- seems like a major design flaw to me.

Comment: The following code is able to reassign a console, does this help you?
`AllocConsole();
    HANDLE hOutputHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD nRet = 0;
    TCHAR buf[100] = { 0 };
    lstrcpy(buf, _T("Hello"));
    WriteConsole(hOutputHandle, buf, lstrlen(buf), &nRet, NULL);
    system("pause");
    FreeConsole();`

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT it says that the `_T` is undefined so i can't test it

Comment: The error is caused by missing header files, you should add `TCHAR.h`.

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT it does open the cmd, tho it does in another window and doesn't put out the text at all

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem? If the reply is helpful, you could mark it as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: well i still can't get it to work, not even with help from one of the devs on the tool, so idk if it actually works, but if it does will i happily do that

Comment: There are many files in the project you uploaded, I can't find the main function entry, which file is the main function in?

Comment: when you're in the Solution Explorer do you go under: Legion/Legion/Main/Main.cpp

Comment: I ran the program you uploaded and it didn't have any errors, I found a section that partially referenced my code, I suggest you make sure the if (cmdline.HasParam(L"--help")) passes and then observe the results when running.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<tchar.h>
int main()
{
    AllocConsole();
    HANDLE hOutputHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD nRet = 0;
    TCHAR buf[100] = { 0 };
    lstrcpy(buf, _T("Hello"));
    WriteConsole(hOutputHandle, buf, lstrlen(buf), &nRet, NULL);
    
    FreeConsole();
    return 0;
}
```

I guess there may be some problems with your project properties, please refer to the following steps to set:
1.Set SubSystem to Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS).

[image]

2.Enter mainCRTStartup in Entry Point.

[image]

After setting the breakpoint we can see the following results:

[image]

Comment: it gives me an error when adding mainCRTStartup `LNK1120` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1120) and `LNK2001` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001)

Comment: here's the code if you wanna take a look https://github.com/biast12/LegionPlusPlus

Comment: @Biast12  Hi, I downloaded and tested your code, it works well. And the LNK error is usually caused by the library file, I found that you did not add the library file directory in the project properties, I suggest you add it and then check the test results.

Comment: you see i'm dumb, i'm not sure how to do that

Comment: @Biast12 Hi,for this issue, I suggest you read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170#to-add-the-dll-header-to-your-include-path) carefully and follow the steps in it.